# C# ArgumentException Image.FromStream with multiple sends on a socket

Tags: c#

I have a little client/server that sends data over a socket via TCP.
Here is the sender:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int sent;
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);

            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                server.Connect(ipep);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to server.");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < 212; i++) {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:/Users/ITFreak/source/repos/CamStream/CamStream/bin/x86/Debug/images/image" + Convert.ToString(i) + ".bmp");

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

            byte[] bmpBytes = ms.ToArray();
            bmp.Dispose();
            ms.Close();

            sent = SendVarData(server, bmpBytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent " + sent + " bytes");

        }

            Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting from server...");
            server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            server.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int SendVarData(Socket s, byte[] data)
        {
            int total = 0;
            int size = data.Length;
            int dataleft = size;
            int sent;

            byte[] datasize = new byte[4];
            datasize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
            sent = s.Send(datasize);

            while (total < size)
            {
                sent = s.Send(data, total, dataleft, SocketFlags.None);
                total += sent;
                dataleft -= sent;
            }
            return total;
        }
    }
```

and the receiver:

```
private static void startListening()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Server is starting...");
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);

            Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            newsock.Bind(ipep);
            newsock.Listen(10);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");

            Socket client = newsock.Accept();
            IPEndPoint newclient = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
            Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}",
                            newclient.Address, newclient.Port);

            while (true)
            {
                int i = 0;
                data = ReceiveVarData(client);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
                try
                {
                    Image bmp = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    Image img2 = new Bitmap(bmp);
                    img2.Save("./images/image " + Convert.ToString(i)  + ".bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    Console.WriteLine("Saved image #" + Convert.ToString(i));
                    i++;
                }
                catch (ArgumentException e)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("something broke");
                }


                if (data.Length == 0)
                    newsock.Listen(10);
            }
            //Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from {0}", newclient.Address);
            client.Close();
            newsock.Close();
        }

        private static byte[] ReceiveVarData(Socket s)
        {
            int total = 0;
            int recv;
            byte[] datasize = new byte[4];

            recv = s.Receive(datasize, 0, 4, 0);
            int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(datasize, 0);
            int dataleft = size;
            byte[] data = new byte[size];


            while (total < size)
            {
                recv = s.Receive(data, total, dataleft, 0);
                if (recv == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                total += recv;
                dataleft -= recv;
            }
            return data;
        }
```

The code works fine if I want to transmit only one image, but fails with an ArgumentException at `Image.FromStream` if I want to transmit all the data.

I could find out that `i` is never increased at the client side, it is always 0.

Does someone see my mistake, why multiple images are not saved accordingly/why is the stream corrupt on my client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `startListening` method, you are declaring `i` inside your `while` loop, do it outside instead:

```
int i = 0;

while (true)
{
    data = ReceiveVarData(client);
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, the value of `i` is set back to 0 on every loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I noticed that about 5 minutes ago, so damn obvious:D